# Place a bounty to reward an answer on a duplicate (closed) question

Tags: feature-request, bounties, duplicate-questions, behavior

Proposal: Allow bounties on questions that are marked as duplicate, which may have valuable answers.

(or make duplicate questions not having the status 'on hold')

---

**Motivation:**

It regularly happens that a closed question has a really good answer. This particularly occurs with questions that are marked as duplicate (questions without intrinsic problems and that may have received good answers before being closed).

Therefore it might occur that a person wishes to place a bounty on the question to reward an existing answer or bring attention to it. However this is not possible under the current system. A duplicate question is a closed question.

This closed status has the undesirable side-effect that the answers given to that question are treated as second class content which can not receive bounties (but also the site does not direct to them, closed questions refer to the parent duplicate question but the other way around does not occur, there is a 'linked' and 'related' list but they are much less visible and in some interfaces, like phone, they do not appear).

Of course one might argue that questions can be merged (or get rid of the on hold status, or repost the answer on the duplicate). But merging would destroy the duplicate (and duplicates are also considered useful). In addition, duplicate questions may be different enough that you can not merge them, or at least it involves a lot of noisy bureaucracy and discussion.

---

**Practical example case, sketch of situation:**

I have searched for duplicate questions with bounties ([query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/1165906/duplicate-questions-where-answers-have-bounties)). I found not so many but it did actually show up an answer of my own. [Why under joint least squares direction is it possible for some coefficients to decrease in LARS regression? [duplicate]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236863/why-under-joint-least-squares-direction-is-it-possible-for-some-coefficients-to).

I believe that this is a good example case where the closed question is still valuable and maybe shouldn't be closed for that reason (yet the 'duplicate link' is still useful). Also, the answer would not be suitable under the duplicate question and merging is not appropriate. The question is duplicate but asked in a very different way and with a different viewpoint angle in mind.

Comment: If someone has a really good answer on a duplicate question then it would probably be good for everyone if they copied it over anyway.

Comment: Or people should spend their time on checking if a question is a duplicate before answering them.

Comment: The idea of duplicates is that good content is together. For this, instead of allowing rewarding these 'hidden' answers, it may be best to either change the order of duplicates (which one is the duplicate target), to suggest merging questions or to move the answer into the main question.

Comment: @curiousdannii I do not think that (copying over the content or merging) is gonna happen a lot. Also sometimes it is not so easy because an answer it is not an exact fit to the parent (near-)duplicate.

Comment: @Luuklag sometimes questions are not easy to find when you try to find them (I regularly have the situation that I *know* a question is out there, but I just can not find the right search terms to find it). It is easier to answer than to find a duplicate. In addition, the answer efforts may actually reveal that a question was a duplicate (e.g. by providing some link with a more general case or some theorem that has been handled before on the site in a similar way). Then due to the answer suddenly a duplicate pops up in the 'Related' questions.

Comment: @Luuklag, continued... here is an example: I answered [a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439530/manual-computation-for-fishers-exact-test-for-tables-larger-than-2-x-2) about Fisher's exact test. It is only *after* I edited/improved the question title that related questions popped up that happened to be duplicate. Those questions did not show up in my initial search. I regularly search whether a question is a duplicate before answering, but I am not gonna play detective.

Comment: @Luuklag In short: Your comment is beside the point.... the reality is that we have lots of duplicate questions with good answers and we need to deal with them.

Comment: @fedorquisaysReinstateMonica Allowing bounties is the minimal change. Making the system such that duplicate questions do not have an order or asymmetric status (one closed the other not) would be indeed better (but also more change to the status quo). Changing the order of duplicates, that is a lot of work and requires noisy discussion. Sometimes it is also not that clear. I believe that people most typically make the more recent question the child duplicate of the earlier/older question.

Comment: Won't this reward answering off-topic questions?

Comment: @Mast duplicate questions are not off-topic. In addition, the reward is in the bounty. You do not get that reward automatically for answering off-topic questions.

Comment: I'd say if the answer is really that valuable, it should be posted on the dupe target so *everyone* benefits.

Comment: @Mast, that is requiring more manual work. The answerer shouldn't be required to do that. In addition, not always is the refered duplicate a good fit to simply copy the answer to the other question.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, using the bounty mechanism to award an existing answer is a patch to begin with. That's not the purpose of a bounty. The purpose is to draw attention to questions.

So, I suggest an alternative: add the ability to give extra reputation points to an existing answer **without a bounty**.

I envision something like this:

> [image]

The blank +50 will appear only after you upvote, with a tooltip like "Award additional rep". Behind the scenes it may work as a bounty, but it won't bump the question, won't have the bounty restrictions, and will be limited in other ways, for example can give only 50 at a time, with a maximum of three times a day.

Comment: While I like this suggested solution, I do feel that it is not correct to allow only the main duplicate question to be bumped by bounties.

Comment: One of the benefits of the current bounty system is that both the question and the answer (which you wanted to reward anyway) get bonus attention. Attention => votes.

Comment: @Mast still, if your goal is only rewarding an answer, it should not have effect on the question and the other answers, IMO.

Comment: Not bumping the question means that the award goes unnoticed, and therefore could be abused. The reason that most interactions bump the question is that this allows the community to see what is going on.

Comment: @CrisLuengo votes also don't bump, what's the difference? With 50 rep for each "bonus", three times a day, it's potential of 150 rep "abuse" a day, where votes are 400. Serial vote detector can be tweaked to check those too, e.g. if a user always give the extra points to the the same other user.

Comment: You can have 3 active bounties, but if they're awarded right away, this does not limit the number of bounties you can award per day. There would have to be an additional restriction. Each bounty can be up to 500 points, so with a 3 bounty per day limit, you could transfer 1500 points to another user per day. That's a significant amount. To transfer 400 rep using upvotes, the other user would need at least 40 questions you haven't upvoted yet.

Comment: This might make it too easy for socks to transfer reputation to another account, especially as it can be overlooked easily as there is no "waiting period" or bumping to the "bounty" question list.

Comment: @SamuelLiew yes, that's a valid concern. Guess it's possible to add some "Answer Award List" screen to mods, where they'll see the awards in a list showing who gave to whom, but it makes this more complicated than what I had in mind. :/